# Can CUDA 10.0 and 10.1 be on the same system?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I want support for both Visual Studio 2019 (which needs CUDA 10.1) and TensorFlow-GPU 1.14 (which needs CUDA 10.0) on a Windows PC. Is there any methods?

I simply installed CUDA 10.0 and CUDA 10.1, and add both directory into environment variable CUDA_PATH. cuDNN is already installed.

The result is Visual Studio can detect CUDA but TensorFlow cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, more than one version of the CUDA toolkit can exist on a system and be used by different applications.

How are you installing TensorFlow-GPU? If you're compiling it yourself, during configuration you can specify the path to whichever version of CUDA that you want to use. If you're installing a pre-built set of binaries (e.g. using something like Anaconda) then that's already been built against a specific version of the CUDA toolkit; you'll need to fetch a different version of the binaries compiled for whichever CUDA toolkit you want, or build it yourself.

If you use Anaconda to install TensorFlow-GPU, you should also receive the correct version of the CUDA toolkit that's needed to run whichever version of TensorFlow-GPU that you've installed; it takes care of those dependencies for you.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm new to CUDA and TensorFlow, and I'm installing with pip. I configured CUDA 10.0 and TensofFlow-GPU 1.13 successfully before. I think I should try installing Anaconda later today.

Comment: Ah-hah; pip is going to install a binary built against a specific version of the CUDA toolkit, so it will always look for only that version. That's the cause of what you saw